# dynamical system, variable in probability distribution

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm not mathematician... I have a question:

If I have a variable $n$ that can evolve in time. This variable have a probability distribution $D$.

Is there a mathematical "tool" that permit to obtain the expression a differential equation such as for any type of distribution $D$:

$\frac{dn}{dt} = f(D,n)$

**EDIT :**
If I do something like : $\frac{dn}{dt} = \tau (D-n)$ does it mean that $n$ will follow $D$ at the velocity $\tau$ ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus

Comment: @caverac, thanks for the link, I didn't really understood yet... I'll have a look more in detail....

Comment: Are you think of something like Brownian motion or a stock market index. These are covered by stochastic calculus (as in caverac's link).